# Resizing UITableViewCell after loading image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am using dynamic height for tableview cells and Haneke for downloading and caching image using the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:ImageCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCellTableViewCell;

    cell.myImageView.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholder: nil)
    return cell
}
```

Here I need to resize the cell height when setting image after downloading.
How can I resize the tableview cell after downloading the image.

Answer (score 2):

Just call

`tableView.beginUpdates() 
 tableView.endUpdates()`

after image is downloaded and height constraint is set. Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Another option, to give the right height to the cell, would be receiving the image size from the server. This way you could feed table with just right calculated cell height.

Comment: But doing this for every cell image will make the scrolling choppy.

Comment: Of course, this has it's drawbacks. I will post another suggestion in the answer.

Comment: From your code, I thought you have only one cell in the table ))

Comment: Can you get the image size from the server?

Comment: no, actually I am getting the image url from web pages.For example I am posting some weblink content inside my app then I will be get the thumbnail image url from that particular site.

Comment: Then, I have no idea how you can achieve your goal.

Comment: worked perfectly for the new autoresizing cells while you need to change their size not in load

Answer (score 1):

just add the proper constraint to your image, for example , top and left constraint with, aspect ratio constraint.(you can do it even in your storyboard interface)

Comment: I already completed those.My question is, for the first time the cell height will be according to the constraints (before downloading),the next time when you scroll to the same row the height will be according to the image height(after downloading).I want the second height to be reflected in the cell automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Set table view's row height like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:ImageCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCellTableViewCell;

    cell.myImageView.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholder: nil)
    tableView.rowHeight = cell.myImageView.frame.origin.y + cell.myImageView.frame.size.height + (constant what every you want to give like: - 20/30 as per your need)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: No, do not do this. The table view's `rowHeight` property should only be set once, not every time a cell is requested.

Comment: but i am using it in my app and it is working fine that is why i have answered